# Find the value of $\lim_{n\to \infty}f'(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity

> Let $x\in [0,0.5]$ and define $f(x):=\begin{cases}x^n\cos(x^{-n}) &\text{ if } x\ne 0\\0 &\text{ if } x=0\end{cases}$. Find the value of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}f'(x)$.

We have, for $x\ne 0$, $f'(x)=\frac nx x^n\cos(x^{-n})+\frac nx \sin(x^{-n})$. Since $x\in [0,0.5]$, so $x^n \to 0$ when $n\to \infty$. Then $x^n\cos(x^{-n}) \to 0$. But I am unable to find out the limit of $f'(x)$ as $n\to \infty$. Any hint. please.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be shown that $f'(0)=0$ and therefore,

$f(x):=\begin{cases}\frac nx x^n\cos(x^{-n})+\frac nx \sin(x^{-n}) &\text{ if } x\ne 0\\0 &\text{ if } x=0\end{cases}$

For $x\ne 0$, Note that $|\frac nx x^n\cos(x^{-n})|\le \frac nx x^n\le \frac n {2^{n}} \implies \frac nx x^n\cos(x^{-n})\to 0$ and

For $x\le 0.5$, the limit for $\frac nx \sin(x^{-n})$ as $n\to \infty$ does not exist and therefore, $f'(x)$ as $n\to \infty$ does not exist for $x\ne 0$ but for $x=0$, $f'(x)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.